# Find the limit of $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}k\arctan{\big(\frac{pk-p+1}{pn}\big)}$

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

> I am required to find the limits of two "siblings" using the same idea, they are:
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin{\left(\frac{1}{pn+r}\right)}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sin{\left(\frac{2pk-2p+r}{2pn}\right)}$$ with $0<r<2p$ and 
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k \arctan{\left(\frac{pk-p+1}{pn}\right)}$$ where $p>1$.

For the first I tried $\sum_{k=1}^{n}sin(\frac{2pk+r}{2pn}-\frac{1}{n})=cos(\frac{1}{n})\sum_{k=1}^{n}sin(\frac{2pk+r}{2pn})-sin(\frac{1}{n})\sum_{k=1}^{n}cos(\frac{2pk+r}{2pn})$ but I don`t know how to find the limit using the ,,squeeze" theorem.
Well, for the second I stumble upon the same problem as to the first: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{n}\arctan{\left(\frac{k}{n}+\frac{p-1}{pn}\right)}$. Is this converging to $\int_{0}^{1}x\arctan{(x)}dx$ as $n\to\infty$? Is this the key ideea?

Comment: Try to use the same idea given for your previous question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3140464/find-lim-limits-n-rightarrow-infty-sum-limits-k-1n-frac1n-sqrtk2

Comment: I've tried but in this case I can`t use fractions. I obtained an upper bound for the second sum but no lower one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. As regards the second sum, note that,
$$0\leq \frac{k-1}{n}\leq \frac{pk-p+1}{pn}\leq \frac{k}{n}\leq 1,$$
for $1\leq k\leq n$ and $p>1$, and it follows that
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{n}\arctan{\big(\frac{k-1}{n}\big)}\leq \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\arctan{\big(\frac{pk-p+1}{pn}\big)}\leq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{n}\arctan{\big(\frac{k}{n}\big)}$$
The left side can be written as
$$\frac{1}{n}\cdot\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\arctan{\big(\frac{k}{n}\big)}+
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{k}{n}\arctan{\big(\frac{k}{n}\big)}.$$
Use a similar approach for the first sum. Since $0<r<2p$, we have that
$$0\leq \frac{k-1}{n}\leq \frac{2pk-2p+r}{2pn}\leq \frac{k}{n}\leq 1$$ for $1\leq k\leq n-1$. Hence
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sin{\left(\frac{k-1}{n}\right)}\leq \sum_{k=1}^{n}\sin{\left(\frac{2pk-2p+r}{2pn}\right)}\leq  \sum_{k=1}^{n}\sin{\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)}.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: I obtained the result $\int_{0}^{1}xarctgxdx$ for the second sum but for the first this approach does not work. My ideea is to use $sin(x-y)=sinxcosy-sinycosx$. So, $\sum_{k=1}^{n}sin(\frac{2pk+r}{2pn}-\frac{1}{n})=cos(\frac{1}{n})\sum_{k=1}^{n}sin(\frac{2pk+r}{2pn})-sin(\frac{1}{n})\sum_{k=1}^{n}cos(\frac{2pk+r}{2pn})$. How can I continue from here?

Comment: @JacobDenicula Are you able to find $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sin{\left(\frac{2pk-2p+r}{2pn}\right)}$? Note that $\sin$ is increasing in $[0,1]$.

Comment: I am unsure I can apply Riemann integration because I remain with an $\frac{r}{2pn}$. Does that reduce when $n$ goes to $\infty$?

Comment: @JacobDenicula Please edit your question with your attempt (detailed) for the first sum.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: Why did you split the sum? See my edit and recall that $\lim_{n\to\infty}n\sin{\left(\frac{1}{pn+r}\right)}=\frac{1}{p}$.